# Django ORM: window function with subsequent filtering

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507828/django-annotate-the-count-of-the-number-of-duplicate-values-for-each-object/51510389#51510389), I [found out](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:description) that window functions are not allowed to combine with filter (technically, they are, but filter clause affects the window). There is a hint to wrap window function in an inner query, so that final SQL looks like this (as I understand):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, *window_function* FROM TABLE)
WHERE *filtering_conditions*
```

The question is: how can I write this query with Django ORM?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It is possible in postgres (see bottom of documentation), but I have no clue how to translate this into the ORM. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: @ilse2005 The given expressions is more like a *Subquery* in the form of *`SELECT ... FROM (SUBQUERY_EXPRESSION) as foo`*. Fortunately, Django has the [**`Subquery(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expression, but it doesn't provide the functionality to specify the ***`FROM`*** clause

Comment: as far as I understood, this is a question of [*How to get a subquery in FROM clause in Django ORM?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633076/how-to-get-a-subquery-in-from-clause-in-django-orm) rather than a Window expression issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another solution is Common Table Expressions (CTE), and with the help of [django-cte](https://pypi.org/project/django-cte/), you could achieve what you want:

```
cte = With(
    YouModel.objects.annotate(
        your_window_function=Window(...),
    )
)

qs = cte.queryset().with_cte(cte).filter(your_window_function='something')
```

Which translates roughly to:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, WINDOW(...) as your_window_function
    FROM yourmodel
) 
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE cte.your_window_function = 'something'
```

Answer (score 3):

[There are developers interested in solving it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/8WTxNcMbj48/jWflYHnDCAAJ) but it's not something possible with the ORM right now.

One proposed solution would be to add a `QuerySet.subquery()` or `.wrap()` method that *pushes* the queryset within a subquery so it can then be filtered.

---

Update, [Django 4.2 will support it](https://github.com/django/django/pull/15922).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this more? Do you have any examples on filtering on a queryset annotated with a window function?

Comment: The ORM doesn't current support it but the idea would be to add a `subquery` method that wraps the current queryset in `SELECT * FROM (queryset_query) as window_subquery` so a subsequent filter can generate a `WHERE` against `window_subquery`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use raw query. In order to do multiple queries at one. for further information [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

```
for p in Person.objects.raw('''
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, *window_function* FROM TABLE)
    WHERE *filtering_conditions*'''):
    print(p)
# John Smith
# Jane Jones
```

Other thing you can do is the following.

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Hero(models.Model):
    # ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    benevolence_factor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        help_text="How benevolent this hero is?",
        default=50
    )
```

querySet.py

```
hero_qs = Hero.objects.filter(category=OuterRef("pk"))
.order_by("-benevolence_factor")

Category.objects.all()
.annotate(most_benevolent_hero=Subquery(hero_qs.values('name')[:1]))
```

Generated SQL would look like this..

```
SELECT "entities_category"."id",
   "entities_category"."name",

  (SELECT U0."name"
   FROM "entities_hero" U0
   WHERE U0."category_id" = ("entities_category"."id")
   ORDER BY U0."benevolence_factor" DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS "most_benevolent_hero"
FROM "entities_category"
```

Comment: Thanks! But using a raw sql is unfortunately not an option. 
Also adding an extra field is not a great solution for my use case.